# How can i access/create nested objects dynamically (go deeper based on a number in a loop)

Tags: javascript, typescript, indexing, nested, javascript-objects

I have a couple of if-statements that do almost exactly the same, just one hierarchy deeper on the `currentHierarchie` object. Can anyone help me put this in a loop (or something). The amount of if statements this way must be the same as `laneAndAllParentLanesIds.length`.

```
private createLaneHierarchieStructure(laneAndAllParentLanesIds: any[], currentHierarchie) {
    for (let i = 0; i < laneAndAllParentLanesIds.length; i++) {
        const obj = currentHierarchie;
        const keys = laneAndAllParentLanesIds;

        if (i === 0 && !obj[keys[i]])
            obj[keys[i]] = {};

        if (i === 1 && !obj[keys[i - 1]][keys[i]])
            obj[keys[i - 1]][keys[i]] = {};

        if (i === 2 && !obj[keys[i - 2]][keys[i - 1]][keys[i]])
            obj[keys[i - 2]][keys[i - 1]][keys[i]] = {};

        if (i === 3 && !obj[keys[i - 3]][keys[i - 2]][keys[i - 1]][keys[i]])
            obj[keys[i - 3]][keys[i - 2]][keys[i - 1]][keys[i]] = {};

        if (i === 4 && !obj[keys[i - 4]][keys[i - 3]][keys[i - 2]][keys[i - 1]][keys[i]])
            obj[keys[i - 4]][keys[i - 3]][keys[i - 2]][keys[i - 1]][keys[i]] = {};
    }
    return currentHierarchie;
}
```

[example response of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdkWH.png) (after calling it multiple times and saving it to the same object (`currentHierarchie`) like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < boards.length; i++) {
    let laneHierarchie = {};
    boards[i]['info']['lanes'].forEach(lane => {
        const laneAndAllParentLanesIds = this.getAllParentLanes(i, lane);
        laneHierarchie = this.createLaneHierarchieStructure(laneAndAllParentLanesIds, laneHierarchie);
    });
    console.log(laneHierarchie);
}
```

Comment: please add the needed data amd the wanted result for running the above code.

Comment: FYI, adding the data as text (rather than an image), is much easier for people reading your question

Comment: i will keep that in mind for next time!
the `laneAndAllParentLanesIds` could have the data `[685920266, 685920267, 689096981]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the `obj` variable declaration and initialization outside of the for loop and take only a single value as key for checking `obj` and assign an empty array if necessary.

Then assign the last property to `obj` for the next loop.

```
const obj = currentHierarchie;

for (let key of laneAndAllParentLanesIds) {
    obj[key] = obj[key] || {};
    obj = obj[key];
}
```

A version with `reduce`

```
void laneAndAllParentLanesIds.reduce((o, id) => o[id] = o[id] || {}, currentHierarchie);
```

Comment: Thanks!! the `reduce` works like a charm, the other solution does not work for me, that one just stacks all the keys like: `1:{2:{3:{4:{5:{6:{7:{endless}}}}}}}`